# evointernal.dat file is not getting copied to output folder

Tags: c#, .net, html-to-pdf, evopdf

I have a .net framework 4.6.2 web application. I recently updated my evopdf to evopdf.HtmlToPdf.NetCore, since they provide a .netstandard2 library. But somehow, when i build the project, evointernal.dat file is not getting copied in the output folder. And it throws winapi 2 error (file not found)

I tried creating sample application in .net6 and it works. I tried creating another sample application in .netframework 4.6.2 and it did not work.

I know i can set the evointernal.dat location in the code base, but is there any other solution for this